# How to update the Environment Properties of an Elastic Beanstalk environment via API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, clojure, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm using the AWS SDK for PHP (but the platform is irrelevant) and would like to update the *Environment Properties* of my Elastic Beanstalk environment:

[image: Elastic Beanstalk Environment Properties]

I've read the doc and the only operation I could find that seems to update a configuration is [UpdateConfigurationTemplate](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/latest/class-Aws.ElasticBeanstalk.ElasticBeanstalkClient.html#_updateConfigurationTemplate).

Can this operation update a single Environment Property in a single environment, without touching any saved configuration? I'm confused by the "template" naming.

Or else, **what's the correct operation to programmatically update a single Environment Property in a single environment?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it in the [updateEnvironment](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/latest/class-Aws.ElasticBeanstalk.ElasticBeanstalkClient.html#_updateEnvironment) operation:

```php
$elasticBeanstalkClient->updateEnvironment([
    'EnvironmentName' => $environment,
    'OptionSettings' => [
        [
            'Namespace'  => 'aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment',
            'OptionName' => $key,
            'Value'      => $value
        ]
    ]
]);
```

I found the correct `Namespace` in the values returned by [describeConfigurationSettings](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/latest/class-Aws.ElasticBeanstalk.ElasticBeanstalkClient.html#_describeConfigurationSettings), and this will likely be the same for any application/environment.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of making this available to Google, here's how to do this in Clojure, using [Amazonica](https://github.com/mcohen01/amazonica):

Add to **project.clj**:

```
:dependencies [[amazonica "0.2.10"]]
```

Then, in your code (or REPL):

```
(require '[amazonica.core :as aws]
         '[amazonica.aws.elasticbeanstalk :as eb])

(def aws-access-key "YOUR ACCESS KEY")
(def aws-secret-key "YOUR SECRET KEY")
(def eb-env-name "YOUR ELASTIC BEANSTALK ENVIRONMENT NAME")

(aws/defcredential aws-access-key aws-secret-key)

(eb/update-environment :environment-name eb-env-name
                       :option-settings [{:namespace "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment"
                                          :option-name "KEY"
                                          :value "VALUE"}])
```